# Radon-Nikodym derivative of two measures a.c. with respect to dominating measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be two measures that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. some dominating measure $\lambda$, i.e. $\nu(dx) = \nu(x) \lambda(dx)$ and $\mu(dx) = \mu(x) \lambda(dx)$. Assume furthermore that $\mu$ dominates $\nu$. I am trying to show that $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} (x) = \nu(x) / \mu(x).$

We have for any $C \in \mathcal{F}$, $$ \nu(C) = \int_C \nu(x) \lambda(dx) = \int_C \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x) \lambda(dx)$$
and $\lambda$-a.e. we have that $\nu(x) = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) \mu(x)$. However i'm failing to conclude from here. Since the support of $\mu$ (which we denote by A) contains that of $\nu$ we could divide by $\mu(x)$ and set $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(x) = \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)}$ on $A$ and set an arbitrary value on the complementary of $\bar{A}$. Since $\mu(\bar{A}) = 0$ i guess this is not an issue?

I am more generally struggling with the following. Assume that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are instead singular, i.e. there exists a set $B$ such that $\nu(B) = 0$ and $\mu(\bar{B}) = 0$. In measure theory the convention is $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$ so its seems that there is no issue with writing
$$ \nu(\Omega) = 1 = \int \nu(x) \lambda(dx) = \int \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(x) \lambda (dx) = \int \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(dx) = \int_{\bar{B}} \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(dx) + \int_B \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(dx)$$
however this doesn't make sense since the term in the right most  equality is $0$ using our convention. I guess my question is, what is stopping us from multiplying and then dividing by $\mu(x)$?

Comment: Why do you think  $ \nu(\Omega) = 1$?

Comment: You have $\nu(dx) = \nu(x) \lambda(dx)$ and $\mu(dx) = \mu(x) \lambda(dx)$. You are assuming that there exists a set $B$ such that $\nu(B) = 0$ and $\mu(\bar{B}) = 0$. 
If $\lambda(\bar{B}) > 0$, you can not divide and multiply by $\mu(x)$ for $x \in \bar{B}$, because $\mu(x)=0$ for $x \in \bar{B}$, and you can not divide and multiply by $0$. 
On the other hand, if $\lambda(\bar{B}) =0$, then you get anyway: $$ \nu(\Omega) = \nu(B) + \nu(\bar{B})= 0 + \int_\bar{B} \nu(x) \lambda(dx) = 0$$

Comment: As to why $\nu(\Omega)=1$ i assumed that i am working with probability measures. Sorry i didn’t mention it

Comment: So $\mu,\nu,\lambda$ are probability measures? or just $\mu,\nu$ while $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: $\mu, \nu$ are prob measures and $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: You have $\nu(dx) = \nu(x) \lambda(dx)$ and $\mu(dx) = \mu(x) \lambda(dx)$. You are assuming that there exists a set $B$ such that $\nu(B) = 0$ and $\mu(\bar{B}) = 0$. 
If you assume that $\nu$ is a probability, then $\lambda(\bar{B}) > 0$, otherwise, you would have $\lambda(\bar{B}) = 0$ and: $$ \nu(\Omega) = \nu(B) + \nu(\bar{B})= 0 + \int_\bar{B} \nu(x) \lambda(dx) = 0$$
Now, since $\lambda(\bar{B}) > 0$, you can not divide and multiply by $\mu(x)$ for $x \in \bar{B}$, because $\mu(x)=0$ for $x \in \bar{B}$, and you can not divide and multiply by $0$.

Comment: In summary: divinding by zero is an undefined operation. You can only do that on zero measure sets because those sets can be "ignored".  But, if $\nu$ is a probability, then $\lambda(\bar{B}) > 0$ and you can not divide by $\mu(x)$ for $x\in \bar{B}$, because $\mu(x)=0$.

Comment: ok great thanks for your answer ! So i guess it is correct that $\nu(dx) = \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(dx)$ when $\mu$ dominates $\nu$?

Comment: Yes, $\nu(dx) = \frac{\nu(x)}{\mu(x)} \mu(dx)$ is correct only when $\mu$ dominates $\nu$.